# Optimize Linq Where, using key

Tags: c#, linq, c#-4.0, linq-to-objects

The basics:

`IDictionary<TKey, TValue>` extends `IEnumerable<T>`

```
public interface IDictionary<TKey, TValue>: .., 
    IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>
{
  ... 
}
```

**The `Enumerable` class provides extension methods that provide the implementation of the `where` clause in LINQ**

```
 public static class Enumerable
 {
   ...

   public static IEnumerable<T> Where(this IEnumerable<T>, 
       bool Func<T> predicate) 
   {
       ...
   } 
 }
```

When using LINQ, the compiler transforms the query syntax into calls of the `Enumerable.Where` method.

When the `IEnumerable<T>` returned from this method is iterated through, the predicate is evaluate on *each* of the items of the collection.

The corresponding items are yielded to the result.

So a request like:

```
var l_res = from n in List where n.key == 1 select n;
```

Will iterate through each of the items in `List`.

If `List` implements `IDictionary<TKey, TValue>`, and the `where` clause is on the property used as the key in the dictionary, how can I leverage the key to avoid the iterating through each record and perform a lookup?

I already know I can test to see if the `IEnumerable<T>` is an `IDictionary<TKey, TValue>` implementation as well, and choose which is the best request to use:

```
if(list is IDictionary<int, T>)
{
   var l_res = ((IDictionary<int, T>) list)[1]; 
}
else
{
   var l_res = from n in List where n.key == 1 select n ;
}
```

But I want to know if I missed something that exists in LINQ that deals with keyed collections like this.

Note: The LINQ-to0SQL provider uses `IQueryable<T>` and Expression trees for the same thing, but my question is about LINQ-to-Objects.

Comment: What is your reason for not using `var l_res = ((IDictionary)list)[1];`?

Comment: Is this _truly_ a performance issue for your application or are you micro-optimizing?

Comment: well, no reason at all. I'm on the process to write OData Provider over .Net MicroFramework. And want to avoid the use of IQueryable which induce huge complexity with Expression tree. Then I wanted to be sure to not miss anything before going further...

Answer (score 0):

No, you aren't missing anything.  The only keyed collection that [LINQ](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb397926.aspx) has knowledge of is the [`Lookup<TKey, TElement>` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb460184.aspx), and even then, it doesn't do anything special, it just drops down to the fact that `Lookup<TKey, TElement>` implements `IEnumerable<IGrouping<TKey, TElement>>`; so in effect, you're iterating through the [`IGrouping<TKey, TElement>` interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb344977.aspx) implementations.

That said, LINQ doesn't have any special knowledge of interfaces beyond the [`IEnumerable<T>` interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9eekhta0.aspx); it just so happens that the [`IDictionary<TKey, TValue>` interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s4ys34ea.aspx) extends `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>`, which is why you can perform operation on it in the first place.

However, for any type where you have a specific lookup mechanism, you need to sniff the type (something that is done in LINQ often) and then call the type-specific action where you can.  If the type-sniffing fails, you can resort to the implementation that works with `IEnumerable<T>`.

Just as you're doing here.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement a custom `Where` on your dictionary that analyzed the expression passed in and if it looks like a keyed access, use special dictionary facilities.

In my opinion, this is just a theoretical option. It shouldn't be done this way. Instead, the filtering mechanism should be adjusted so that it uses the dictionary in the right way.

Also note, that once you pass an opaque `Func<T, bool>` to some other code, this other piece of code cannot look inside the delegate you passed in. It cannot notice that there is a keyed access. So that is why LINQ to Objects *cannot* do this.